# how to find the key of the minimum value in a nested json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, key

I have a JSON as shown below. Every group has a name, percent_cpu and percent_memory key. As an example I have shown up to 2 groups, there can be up to N.

```
[
  {
      "name": "esx1",
      "percent_cpu": 10,
      "percent_memory": 20,
  },
  {
      "name": "esx2",
      "percent_cpu": 30,
      "percent_memory": 15,
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to compare each group based on percent_cpu key and find out the lowest value and get the value of the name key from that group.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or show me an example that would be great.

The answer that I'm looking for here is `[{"name":"esx1"}, {"name":"esxN"}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` can accept a `key` argument.

So, assuming you loaded your json into the list `l`, `min(l, key= lambda s: s["percent_cpu"])` should give you

```
  {
      "name": "esx1",
      "percent_cpu": 10,
      "percent_memory": 20,
  }
```